# Find element from document

Tags: mongodb

i've passed a mysql database to mongoDB for a project. My db is about a pharmacy. I have a collection of factures, where which has the list of medicines sold. I'm trying to find the medicine which was sold the most.

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5c3c71f2760c4f47c701fe13"),
"cliente" : {
    "tlmv" : "910987654",
    "nome" : "Josefina Vivida da Paz",
    "nif" : "122133144",
    "pontos" : NumberLong(0),
    "id" : NumberLong(2),
    "pass" : "1eab06cab995dfeb32b6b7c709b8a6c62cabacfe",
    "email" : "josefina@hotmail.pt"
},
"data_f" : ISODate("2018-06-03T00:00:01Z"),
"data_s" : ISODate("2018-06-02T23:55:59Z"),
"desconto" : 0,
"funcionario" : {
    "tlmv" : "934567123",
    "nome" : "Pedro Jorge Rito Lima",
    "ordenado" : 800.32,
    "iban" : "PT 50 2751 3262 76598707612",
    "pass" : "3cfa1c281281ffe4f5db2ccfbe7a17f8a9479808",
    "niss" : "14385639201",
    "id" : NumberLong(2),
    "cedula" : "54321"
},
"id" : NumberLong(15),
"id_c" : NumberLong(2),
"id_func" : NumberLong(2),
"medicamentos" : [
    {
        "categoria" : "Analg�sico",
        "receita" : "N",
        "des" : "Ben-U-Ron 500",
        "qt" : 20,
        "formato" : "granulado",
        "qt_v" : NumberLong(1),
        "pos" : "A12",
        "lab" : "Laborat�rio do Rio Ave",
        "preco_l" : 2.51,
        "un" : "un",
        "preco" : 2.51,
        "preco_v" : 2.51,
        "id" : NumberLong(1),
        "stock" : NumberLong(21)
    },
    {
        "categoria" : "Estatina",
        "receita" : "S",
        "des" : "Sinvastatina",
        "qt" : 30,
        "formato" : "comprimido",
        "qt_v" : NumberLong(1),
        "pos" : "K23",
        "lab" : "Mylan",
        "preco_l" : 16.45,
        "un" : "un",
        "preco" : 16.45,
        "preco_v" : 16.45,
        "id" : NumberLong(6),
        "stock" : NumberLong(25)
    }
],
"pontos_r" : NumberLong(10),
"pontos_u" : NumberLong(0),
"total" : 18.96
```

}

So my objective is to count every medicine -"medicamento"- sorted by different descriptions-"des". Similiar to Count on mysql. Any ideas how? The code above is abount 1 facture.

Comment: Could you paste expected result for this JSON ?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. If this was the only facture it would be:
"Ben-u-ron" : 1
"Sinvastatina" : 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) to get a medicine per document and then [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) with `$sum` to get count per medicine, try:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: "$medicamentos"
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$medicamentos.des",
            count: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: What a legend! thanks a lot mate :D Just one more thing, is there a way to only appear the "medicamentos.des" and the number, without the "_id" and "count"?

Comment: You have to return an array of JSON objects from MongoDB query but sometimes people prefer following format:  https://mongoplayground.net/p/yBX3VPyw7BI